# shutting down Windows with warning to the user

Tags: windows, shutdown

I see that shutdown.exe can be used to shutdown or restart a machine.  However, the warning given to the user doesn't offer any way to cancel the shutdown (other than doing "shutdown /a" in a command line prompt).

Is there a different way of shutting down Windows that offers the user some easy way to cancel out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your own program that calls [`ExitWindowsEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376871(v=vs.85).aspx). It can allow any cancel operations you want.